# How can i enable CORS on google cloud function .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, firebase, google-cloud-platform

i have function pdf set protect password service function on google cloud but i can't call service from my react js website. because service is block by CORS

my function on google cloud .NET Core 3.1

```
namespace SimpleHttpFunction
{
    public class Function : IHttpFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Function(ILogger<Function> logger) =>
        _logger = logger;

    public async Task HandleAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        // Check URL parameters for "message" field
        string message = request.Query["message"];

        // If there's a body, parse it as JSON and check for "message" field.
        using TextReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body);
        string text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        if (text.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                JsonElement json = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(text);
                if (json.TryGetProperty("message", out JsonElement messageElement) &&
                    messageElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.String)
                {
                    message = messageElement.GetString();
                }
            }
            catch (JsonException parseException)
            {
                _logger.LogError(parseException, "Error parsing JSON request");
            }
        }
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(message ?? "HelloWorld");
    }

}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests may help…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Mr.Joachim Isaksson for Answer.

```
    HttpRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpResponse response = context.Response;

    // Set CORS headers
    //   Allows GETs from any origin with the Content-Type
    //   header and caches preflight response for 3600s

    response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (HttpMethods.IsOptions(request.Method))
    {
        response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
        response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
        return;
    }
```